# Is polling gps location data within a non-wakeful Service a good practice?

Tags: android, service, gps, location

In a regular activity, it is mandatory to register to LocationManager when we want to receive updates, and remove updates sometime later, e.g. within onPause() for instance.

However, in a non-wakeful service, which can die at any given time, how can I assure that the LocationManager is not keeping the GPS on?
(I have no guarantee that the onDestroy method of the service will actually get called, and even a foreground Service might get killed...)

I am asking this since I couldn't find any warning regarding polling location within a service, but I suspect that it might be a bad habit overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimenting with forcing stop of Services, it seems that the location manager
is smart enough to turn off the GPS whenever a LocationListener is dead,
so case is closed...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a service that can run with a interval. Service also contains a instance of your LocationManager and your current activity Context.

When your activity is destroyed your Context will be set to null and you can stop locationrequest and service by itself.

Comment: Indeed my Service gets woken-up once again after being killed,
but it is not in an Activity Context most of the time, (thus the onDestroy of the activity will not be sufficient).

Whenever the Service gets killed, I have no opportunity to gracefully stop location requests,
let alone the problem that rises from asking for requests once again, with another location listener instance - whenever the Service gets resurrected.... (START_STICKY is used)

Comment: Maybe with a broadcast receiver?

Comment: I don't see how that can help. The logical answer I searched but couldn't find supporting evidence for, is that the LocationManager is smart enough to not continue polling the gps once a listener reference is disposed, otherwise that defeats the purpose of polling the gps inside a Service....